# detecting Losseless-join

Tags: relational-database, inner-join, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

Consider a database R = {Ra} with Ra = {A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6} and the dependencies
F = {A1 → A2, A2 → A3, A3 → A4, A4 → A2, A3 → A5}.

Consider R1 = {A1, A2}, R2 = {A2, A3, A4}, R3 = {A1, A2, A5}, R4 = {A3, A4}.

How can I tell if R1,R2,R3,R4 is a losseless-join decomposition

Comment: What database technology, query language etc. do you use?

Comment: Its a theoretical question, we haven't learned any specific language

Comment: The question is not clear though.

Comment: I think the question is clear, but the research effort is not.

Comment: @ciuak, if you don't know what you're talking about, then don't comment.  Since the question is about functional dependency theory, it should be clear to anyone knowledgeable (not you, apparently) that the "database technology" is "relational technology" and "which query language" is completely besides the point, since functional dependency theory is independent of query language.

Answer (score 2):

The decomposition you gave cannot possibly be lossless in any meaning of the word because your input schema has A6 but your decomposition does not mention it.